# jQuery matching href to variable and adding class

Tags: jquery

I have a hash in my url such as `http://domain.com/#http://google.com`

which is collected by `var urlfromhash = window.location.hash.substr(1);`

I have been trying to highlight the link in my list where the `href` matches `urlfromhash`

$('.col-left a').addClass('highlight');

Everything I find seems to say `.each()` but seem more work than what I would need here.

Comment: Can you create jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS attribute selector like this:

```
$('a[href^="'+urlfromhash+'"]').addClass('highlight');
```

> an a element whose "href" attribute value begins exactly with the string "urlfromash"

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VN3fa/1/)

Also checkout the [W3C Documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors) about selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [`attribute-equals`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector:

```
$('.col-left a[href="' + urlfromhash + '"]').addClass('highlight');
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you wish to select an 'a' element with a href value that matches the value of the variable. In that case.

```
$('.col-left a[href="' + urlfromhash + '"]').addClass('highlight');
```

would match all a's with a href that has exactly the same value as the variable

This will work for any attribute and could therefore also be used to say select on `ref`. In the general usage it doesn't have to be an explicit match (in your case it does of course).